# View Models in Servlets / MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, servlets

I am building an application with simple Servlets and the MVC pattern. I am not using any framework like Spring.

I have some Model classes like this:

```
public class BlogPost {

private List<Comment> _comments;

// Things
}
```

and

```
public class Comment {
// Code
}
```

Posts can have zero or more comments associated with them in that collection.

However, I want to attach some additional information to the BlogPost Model before it is passed to the View, namely a value I set in a Cookie once a user makes a comment on a BlogPost. Strictly speaking, this is not a part of the BlogPost Model itself -- it is unrelated, incidental information, however I am not sure if I should make it easy on myself and just add it to the BlogPost class or do something to abstract this out a bit more.

So, should I add a field to the BlogPost class to handle this additional value, OR should I make a "View Model" along the lines of this which gets passed to the JSP view:

```
public class BlogPostView {

public BlogPostView(BlogPost bp, String message) {
  // Constructor stuff, save these to instance variables
}

public BlogPost getBlogPost() { /* ... */ }
public String getMessage() { /* ... */ }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If BlogPost and your cookie data are unrelated, it is a bad idea to put the cookie data in your BlogPost class. The BlogPost class should represent what it's called - a blog post. It would be confusing to have other data associated.

Your second option of creating a class specifically to pass to the view is a better idea, though I'm curious to know why you need to pass the blog post and the cookie data as one object to your view? If you're using raw servlets:

```
request.setAttribute("blogPost",blogPost);
request.setAttribute("cookieData",cookieData);
```

Using a model class (e.g. Spring MVC ModelMap):

```
model.addAttribute("blogPost",blogPost);
model.addAttribute("cookieData",cookieData);
```

Your view will have access to both pieces of data, which you can manipulate using JSTL or other tag libraries.

If there's something I'm missing, can you elaborate more?

Comment: Also, at the risk of sounding anal... do not prefix your instance variables with an underscore -  it's not correct java naming convention. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I also didn't know about the naming convention thing. I will look at some Java style guides for advice on that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a HashMap model - and pass it along with the response to view.
model.put("blog", blog)
model.put("message", "some message")